# Using space character in string value in windows registry

Tags: registry

I have defined new extension(.abc) in windows registry by using following instructions:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\abcApp_V1\shell\open\command]
@="D:\myDirecoty\abcApp.exe \"%1\""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.abc]
@="abcApp_V1"
```

This works properly and now each file with .abc extension opens the abcApp.exe program.

I have changed the Directory name to **my Directory** (add space between my & Directory):

```
@="D:\my Direcoty\abcApp.exe \"%1\""
```

It doesn't work! and the files with .abc extensions dont open abcApp.exe

What's the problem? Should I replace **space** with an special character?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed it like this and it works well:

```
"D:\my Direcoty\abcApp.exe" "%1"
```

Thanks